# How to display selected option when update a data in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, css, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

Please help, how do I display the data in the selected data update dropdown?

MODEL
this is the appearance of the model

```
// Ambil data sebelum ubah (Edit Gembala cool)
public function edit_gembala_cool($table, $where)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($table, $where);
}
```

CONTROLER
this is the appearance of the controler

```
 // EDIT GEMBALA COOL
public function edit_gembala_cool($id)
{
    $data['title'] = 'Edit Data Gembala COOL';
    $data['gembala_cool'] = $this->db->where('id_cool', $id)->get('cool')->row();
    $data['kategori'] = $this->db->get('cool_kategori')->result_array();

    $id_cool = $this->input->post('id_cool');
    $where = array('id_cool' => $id_cool);
    $this->load->model('Gembala_model');
    $gembala_cool = $this->Gembala_model->edit_gembala_cool('cool', $where)->result();

    echo json_encode($gembala_cool);

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/topbar', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebar', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/edit_gembala_cool', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

VIEW
this is the appearance of the View

```
<select name="kategori_cool" id="kategori_cool" class="form-control" required>
   <option value="">--pilih--</option>
   <?php foreach ($kategori as $k) { ?>
       <option <?php if ($k->kategori_id == "your desired id") {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="<?php echo $k->kategori_id ?>"><?php echo $k->kategori_cool ?>
       </option>
   <?php } ?>
</select></div>
```

MY RESULT
this is the appearance of the my result view

[image: MY RESULT]

Answer (score 0):

> You forgot to made else condition

```
    <select name="kategori_cool" id="kategori_cool" class="form-control" required>
   <option value="">--pilih--</option>
   <?php foreach ($kategori as $k) { ?>
       <option <?=($k->kategori_id == "your desired id")?'selected="selected"':"";?>  
       value="<?=$k->kategori_id ?>"><?=$k->kategori_cool?>
       </option>
   <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: display successfully, but data is not automatically selected when pressed the EDIT button

Comment: you should pass the selected id into <option <?=($k->kategori_id == "HERE PASS THE ID ")?'selected="selected"':"";?>